# How to improve the time complexity of this algorithm that has nested loops?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, nested-loops

Input:

Given an array of integers `T = [t0, t1, t2, ... tk]` representing a row where each element is the maximum waiting time. And an array `E = [e0, e1, e2, ... ei]` representing all possible expiration times. Finally, an integer `K` is given which is the maximum size of a container.

Problem:

For each expiration time `E`, it is necessary to obtain the position of the last element `T` that was able to enter the container of size K, and each waiting time in `T` must be greater than or equal to the expiration time `E` to be able to enter the container.

Example Case 1:

Input:

```
K = 2; T = [1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6]; E = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Output:

```
Kth = [2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Explanation:

In `E[0]`, the expiration time is 1, so the 2nd in row `T` will be the last to enter the container, so `Kth[0] = 2nd`;

In `E[1]`, the expiration time is 2, so the 3rd in row `T` will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so `Kth[1] = 3rd`;

In `E[2]`, the expiration time is 3, so the 3rd in row `T` will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so `Kth[2] = 3rd`;

In `E[3]`, the expiration time is 4, so the 3rd in row `T` will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so `Kth[3] = 3rd`;

In `E[4]`, the expiration time is 5, in this case almost all elements of `T` except the last one have expired, however, as it was not possible to complete the container, it must return position 0, therefore `Kth[4] = 0`;

And so on for `E[5]` and `E[6]`.

Here is the code I've been able to come up with but it runs in O(E * T) time which is too slow for the performance constraints:

```
public static List<Integer> kthElement(int k, List<Integer> T, List<Integer> E) {
    List<Integer> kthElements = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < E.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(E.get(i));

        int currentElement = 0;
        int elementsFilled = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < T.size(); j++) {
            if (elementsFilled >= k || k > T.size()) {
                break;
            }

            if (T.get(j) >= E.get(i)) {
                elementsFilled++;
                currentElement = j + 1;
            }
        }

        if (elementsFilled >= k) {
            kthElements.add(currentElement);
        } else {
            kthElements.add(0);
        }

    }

    return kthElements;
}
```

How can I improve the performance of this algorithm?

Comment: first sort the arrays - then you can stop the search as soon as you find your matches...

Comment: @Randy When I sort the ArrayLists, I lose the original positioning, which I need to infer the order in which in the kth elements should be returned.

Comment: If you need the original index you could always create a new int[][] which contains the value and index and then sort it based on the value. That way you will have the original index.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily do this in O(E + T) instead of O(E x T).

The loop is quite simple, and will appear to be O(E x T) at first glance because of the nesting, but the inner loop never gets reset within the outer loop so it is indeed O(E + T).

I will assume that E < 65536 in the following code.

```
    List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();
    int inPos = 0;
    int kCnt = 0;
    int last = 0;
    int[] kTracker = new int[65536];
    for (int i = 0; i < E.size(); i++)
    {
        // Remove Expired
        kCnt -= kTracker[i];

        // Fill Container
        while (kCnt < K && inPos < T.length)
        {
            int exp = i + T.get(inPos);
            if (exp < kTracker.length)
            {
                // don't bother tracking if > E.max, as it won't affect the output.
                kTracker[exp]++;
            }
            last = inPos;
            kCnt++;
            inPos++;
        }

        // record output
        out.add(last);
    }
```

If there aren't guarantees on E.max, but there are guarantees on T.max, and we constrain memory, then we can implement a rolling array instead.

For example, if T.max = 10, we can use the below code to replace bits from the code above...

```
// Creating a rolling kTracker
int kTrackerNow = 0;
int[] kTracker = new int[10];
...
// Expiring elements
kCnt -= kTracker[kTrackerNow];
kTracker[kTrackerNow] = 0;

// Progressing to the next time period
kTrackerNow = (kTrackerNow + 1) % kTracker.length;

// Tracking a new item from T[inPos]
kTracker[(kTrackerNow + T[inPos]) % kTracker.length]++;
```

Finally, if we don't have any guarantees on the input, we can use HashMap<> to replace the tracking array.  As the HashMap will perform memory allocation for each and every element, it will be far slower than the above 2 solutions, but it can deal with all kinds of input without restriction.

```
    List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();
    int inPos = 0;
    int kCnt = 0;
    int last = 0;
    Map<Integer, Integer> kTracker = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < E.size(); i++)
    {
        // Remove Expired
        Integer removed = kTracker.remove(i);
        if (removed != null)
        {
            kCnt -= removed;
        }

        // Fill Container
        while (kCnt < K && inPos < T.length)
        {
            kTracker.put(i + T.get(inPos), kTracker.getOrDefault(i + T.get(inPos), 0) + 1);
            last = inPos;
            kCnt++;
            inPos++;
        }

        // record output
        out.add(last);
    }
```